# Retrieve XML data from ASP.NET SOAP Service to ASP.NET aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, oracle, web-services

I have web service which return XML data when user input Id. If ID exist in database it will return XML data, and now I create `Test Project` which I as reference use this `SOAP Services`.

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataTable GetAkontasById(int Id)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=test-1:1521/test;USER ID=test;PASSWORD=test");
        OracleDataAdapter dr = new OracleDataAdapter("Select * from AKONTAS where A_KONTO= '" + Id + "'", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add("AKONTAS");
        dr.Fill(ds, "AKONTAS");
        DataTable tt = ds.Tables[0];
        return tt;
    }
```

This is how my xml look like after run `Web Service`

```
<DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="AKONTAS" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="AKONTAS" msprop:BaseTable.0="AKONTAS">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="A_KONTO" msprop:BaseColumn="A_KONTO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="NAZIV" msprop:BaseColumn="NAZIV" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="SIFRA_RAD" msprop:BaseColumn="SIFRA_RAD" msprop:OraDbType="104" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="OPSTINA" msprop:BaseColumn="OPSTINA" msprop:OraDbType="104" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MB" msprop:BaseColumn="MB" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ULICA" msprop:BaseColumn="ULICA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="BROJ" msprop:BaseColumn="BROJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PBROJ" msprop:BaseColumn="PBROJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="MJESTO" msprop:BaseColumn="MJESTO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PORESKI" msprop:BaseColumn="PORESKI" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TRANSAKCIJ" msprop:BaseColumn="TRANSAKCIJ" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="INTERNET" msprop:BaseColumn="INTERNET" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="EMAIL" msprop:BaseColumn="EMAIL" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="KONTAKT" msprop:BaseColumn="KONTAKT" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TELEFON" msprop:BaseColumn="TELEFON" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="FAKS" msprop:BaseColumn="FAKS" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DAT_UNOS" msprop:BaseColumn="DAT_UNOS" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PDVMB" msprop:BaseColumn="PDVMB" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="VRSTA_KLIJENTA" msprop:BaseColumn="VRSTA_KLIJENTA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DRZAVA" msprop:BaseColumn="DRZAVA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<AKONTAS diffgr:id="AKONTAS1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<A_KONTO>515534</A_KONTO>
<NAZIV>ABC</NAZIV>
<SIFRA_RAD>30017</SIFRA_RAD>
<MB>123456789000</MB>
<DAT_UNOS>2005-12-07T00:00:00+01:00</DAT_UNOS>
</AKONTAS>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

And right now O create `aspx` page which contain as reference `Web Service.`
This `aspx` also needs to return XML data, and right now I stuck here and have no idea how to take this XML data and pass it to `aspx` page. 
What do you suggest me to do ?

```
protected void btnProjeri_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AkontasService.AkontasSoapClient client =
                new AkontasService.AkontasSoapClient();
            var rezultat = client.GetAkontasById(Convert.ToInt32(txtAkonto.Text));
            txtRezultat.Text = rezultat.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: This is 3rd time you are asking question.  You have an XML with embedded schema and a datatable.  You also have an invalid xml with xmlns and no namespace like "id" for the dataset.

Comment: What do you mean by embedded schema and a datatable ?
invalid xml with xmlns and no namespace like "id" for the dataset

Comment: @jdweng Please don not speak about something you are not familiar with. 
DataSet and DataTable are only and only which can be used to retrieve data from database. 
I am asking about Consuming data from SOAP service.

Comment: Look at this post 
https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-create-web-service-in-asp-dot-net-web-forms-with-example-csharp-vb-net.html

Comment: Hounderd of pages and post I read about your answer and in every post I get same result. One of that you can read it in post above

Comment: https://imgur.com/XKAtfRO 
Where is errors  @jdweng?

Comment: The errors look like they were fixed from previous postings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication132
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            List<XElement> AKONTAS = doc.Descendants("AKONTAS").ToList();

            var results = AKONTAS.Select(x => x.Elements().Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(y.Name.LocalName, (string)y)).ToList()).ToList();

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result.Select(x => x.Key + " : " + x.Value)));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Pleas read my question one more time pleaseeee. I don't need 
const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
Since I get XML from my SOAP Services, I dont want to read from .xml file

Comment: What does it mean this line of code ?
 const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

Comment: For testing I just put xml into a file..  You just need to use XDocument.Parse(string).

Comment: System.Xml.XmlException: 'Root element is missing.'

Comment: I have no idea what this piece of code does, but as I check and debugged it, it look like nothing. 
What ever I pass it only open console and close it, second time when I run it I get error, third time when I run it also nothing happened

Comment: The code works when I read the posted xml from file.  The xml must start as first character in string, otherwise , you will get an exception.

Comment: I updated code to output data so it is easy to see results.  I also changed the SelectMany to just a Select.

Comment: Did you copy this output.xml data and past it to C:\TEMP\Test.xml ?

Comment: Yes,it works now :) 
But it looks I need always copy-past code from SOAP Services to .XML file

Comment: You need to carefully look at soap.  If you paste into notepad use SaveAs and then check encoding to see if it is UTF8.  The soap may be using a different encoding.